# How to redirect to specific section of the third party web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I'm currently at "mehere.com" and if I click a button from there, I want the page to redirect to "gothere.com" then scroll down to the section that has id="rightHere".
So I tried 2 different ways and both redirects to the page successfully, but does not scroll down to section. Page loads then stays at top of the screen.

```
// #1 Method
<button onclick="Redirect()">Click</button>

function Redirect() {
         window.location.href = "https://www.gothere.com#rightHere";
        }
// #2 Method
<button><a href="https://www.gothere.com#rightHere">Click</a></button>
```

Is there a alternative way to get screen to scroll down to specific specific section of the page with JavaScript?

Comment: You don't have scripting control over an external site, so you'll need a relevant anchor on the site as it exists.

Comment: This is unrelated to your query, but it's invalid HTML to put a link inside a button.

Comment: Have you tried just `<a href="https://www.gothere.com#rightHere">Click</a>` ?

Comment: maybe try something like this on the landing page: `var location = window.location.hash.substr(1);
document.getElementById(location).scrollIntoView(true);` You may need to check that the element exist first.

Comment: Yeah tried just <a href="https://www.gothere.com#rightHere">Click</a> , but still don't work. My guess is as per pilchard, since I don't have access to scripting of external web page, I can only redirect there, but can't make it scroll to certain section.

Comment: windown.location.hash then document.getElementById(id).click() worked. Thanks Gabriel!

Comment: Put it as answer. @JudoboyAlex

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no alternative way. We need the id to scroll to a specific part of the page.

The most ideal method for solving the problem;

```
<a href="https://www.gothere.com#rightHere">Click</a>
```

Also, you don't need to add a button tag, this is more ideal.